# Insert vertices at edges intersections in 3DS Max

Tags: 3d, script, 3ds-max

What is the fast and precise way to insert vertices at edges intersections?
Considering I have geometry like on the image:
[image]
I want to achieve result like this (new vertices marked with red dots):
[image]

Comment: Are the lines in the same plane? Your image looks like in 3D there's no intersection, the crossing is only in the 2D projection.

Comment: Only 2D, since there are only planes